# On the mapping cylinder inclusion $i : X \hookrightarrow M_f$ being a cofibration.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, cofibrations

I'm trying to prove that given a continuous map $f : X \to Y$, the inclusion

$$
i : x \in X \mapsto [(x,1)] \in M_f
$$

is a cofibration.

Given a homotopy $H : X \times I \to W$ and $g : M_f \to W$ so that

$$
H(x,0) = gi(x) = g([(x,1)])
$$

we want a homotopy $J : M_f \times I \to W$ such that for all $x \in X$ we have

$$
J([(x,1)],t) = H(x,t) \text{ and } J([(x,0)],t) = g(f(x)).
$$

Since $g$ is a function with domain $M_f$, which is a pushout, we have continuous functions $g_X : X \times I \to W$ and $g_Y : Y \to W$ such that 
$$
g_Y(y) = g([y]), \quad g_X(x,t) = g([(x,t)]),
$$

and $g_X(x,0) = g_Y(f(x))$.

Now, since $I$ is locally compact Hausdorff, by the exponential law the endofunctor 
$$- \times I : \mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Top}$$
is left adjoint to $\mathsf{Top}(I,-)  :\mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Top}$. Hence the former preserves colimits and so $M_f \times I$ is the pushout of $X \times I \xrightarrow{i_0 \times 1} (X \times I) \times I$ and $X \times I \xrightarrow{f \times 1} Y \times I$. Thus, the map $J$ corresponds to a certain selection of maps $\tilde{H} : (X \times I) \times I \to W$ and $\tilde{g} : Y \times I \to W$ so that 
$$\tilde{g}(f(x),t) = \tilde{H}(x,0,t).$$

My intuition here is to leave the 'initial data' $g$ fixed on $Y$, and at each instant $s$ to have a function from $X \times I$ that behaves like $H_0$ in the bottom face and coinides with $H_s$ at the top face. This would make $J$ an extension of the original homotopy. Hence I wanted to define

$$
\tilde{H}(x,s,t) = H(x,ts) \text{ and } \tilde{g}(y,t) =g_Y(y).
$$

However, for these to induce a map from $M_f$ we should have that $g([(x,0)]) = g([(x,1)])$ for all $x \in X$. But moreover, for the induced map to preserve the initial data, one should have $g = Ji_0$ and $H = J(i \times 1_I)$ which amounts to proving

$$
g([(x,t)]) = g([(x,0)]) \quad (\forall t \in I).
$$

It is not evident to me that this is the case. What's missing here? Are my choices for $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{g}$ incorrect? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the desired $J$ you have the requirements $J(i \times 1_I) = H$ which means
$$J([x,1],t) = H(x,t)$$
and the requirement $Ji_0 = g$ which means
$$J([x,t],0) = g([x,t]) =g_X(x,t), J([y],0) = g([y]) = g_Y(y).$$
Here we know that $g_X(x,0) = g_Y(f(x))$.

$J$ is induced by maps $\tilde{g} : Y \times I \to W, \tilde{H} : (X \times I) \times I \to W$ such that

(1) $\tilde{g}(f(x),t) = \tilde{H}(x,0,t)$.

Thus the above two requirements translate to

(2) $\tilde{H}(x,1,t) = H(x,t)$

(3) $\tilde{H}(x,t,0) = g_X(x,t), \tilde{g}(y,0) = g_Y(y)$

Now we face a serious problem: The only chance to give an *explicit* definition of $\tilde{g}$ is to refer to $g_Y$ and to take $g(y,t) = g_Y(y)$. But in general this does not work as you have seen. Therefore we need a completely different approach based on some deeper theorems about cofibrations.

See [Mapping cylinder cofibration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1198336) for a solution.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. I'll look into that post.